# Rolling at Least 2 2's on 3 fair dice

Tags: probability, statistics

Say we roll three 6-sided dice.

What is the probability that at least two of the faces are a 2?

The sample space here is 216.

Rolling a 2 on one dice is 1/6.

Rolling two 2s is 1/6 * 1/6 = 1/36

The third dice is at least two 2s so the probability it isn't a 2 is 5/6 and the probability it is a 2 is 1/6.

So do we multiply 1/36 * 1/6 * 5/6 to get the answer?

5/1296 is the probability of rolling at least two 2s on 3 fair dice?

Comment: Why is the sample space 64?

Comment: The calculation of $\frac{1}{36}\cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}=\frac{5}{1296}$ is the probability that when rolling *four* dice *in sequence* that very specifically the first die is a $2$, the second die is a $2$, the third die is a $2$ and the fourth die is not a $2$.  On the other hand, $\frac{1}{36}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\color{red}{+}\frac{5}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{36}$ which you probably meant to write is the probability that when rolling three dice *in sequence* that the first die is a 2, the second die is a 2, and the third die is either a 2 or not a 2.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{36}$, being the probability that the first two dice are specifically twos while the third die is whatever misses counting scenarios where the first die wasn't a 2 but the second and third were, or similarly where the first and third dice were 2's but the second die wasn't, etc...

Comment: @callculus I can only guess that the OP had meant to write `6^4` instead of `64`., but that is also incorrect as alluded to elsewhere.  It should have been $6^3$.

Answer (score 2):

The following rolls are all possible:

$$2,2,1 \\ 2,1,2 \\ 1,2,2 \\ \vdots \\ 2,2,6 \\ 2,6,2 \\ 6,2,2$$

The probability of getting exactly two $2$'s followed by a non-$2$: $$\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{5}{6}$$

The probability of getting a $2$, a non-$2$, then a $2$:

$$\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{5}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{6}$$

The probability of getting a non-$2$, then two $2$'s:

$$\dfrac{5}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{6}$$

The probability of getting three $2$'s:

$$\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{6}$$

Adding this up, the probability of at least two $2$'s is:

$$\dfrac{3\cdot 5}{6^3}+\dfrac{1}{6^3} = \dfrac{2}{27}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can also split it into two separate independent parts - one is rolling *exactly* two 2's on 3 dice, and the other is rolling exactly three 2's on 3 dice.

For the first part, we use Bernoulli scheme, as we want precisely 2 successes in 3 trials, with success probability of 1/6:

$$\binom{3}{2} \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{5}{6} = \dfrac{5}{72}$$

For the second part, we want all 3 trials to roll 2:

$$\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^3 = \dfrac{1}{216}$$

As these two cases above are independent of each other, we can add their probabilities - so the sum is

$$\dfrac{5}{72} + \dfrac{1}{216} = \dfrac{2}{27}$$

as in the other answer.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  If you type `$$\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$$`, you will obtain $$\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$$  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) contains information about typesetting mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you so much @N.F.Taussig